# How to change background color of each div created by a loop?

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I have a loop that creates div. I have 4 colors which I want to be the background color of each div without using javascript. Can anyone have any idea how to do it?

```
@foreach (var names in Model.Projects.Value) {
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div class="Projects">
            @names.Name
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are creating div?

Comment: can you also post the code how you defined the colors?

Comment: I am using css for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a tag about the underlying framework/library you are using. Dynamically assigning attribute values differs from one mvc framework to another.

Now, from the code you have have shared, I assume `Model.Projects.Value` is an array/array-like structure holding multiple objects. Each object has some properties like 'Name', as I see you access it using `@name.Name`.

I would suggest to take this approach. Defines few classes in your CSS stylesheet like below,

```
.class_name1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.class_name2 {
  background-color: blue;
} 
....
```

and define another property named `class` for each object in `Model.Projects.Value`. Give a value to this 'class' property from one of the classes you have defined, say `class_name1`.

In your html code, assign the class dynamically like below:

```
@foreach (var names in Model.Projects.Value) {
    <div class="col-xs-4 @names.class">
        <div class="Projects">
            @names.Name
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

You might have to figure out if the syntax to bind object property with attribute (`class="col-xs-4 @names.class"`) differs from what I have shown above.

Comment: Is there any other way without using the model